# $\frac{dy}{dx}=ye^{x}-\exp\left(e^{2x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}=ye^{x}-\exp\left(e^{2x}\right)$$

I've found the solution to the homogenous equation: $y = C \exp(e^x)$.

Please give me a hint, how to figure out the general solution?

Comment: Try plugging in $y=C(x)*\exp(\exp(x)). This is called variation of parameters.

Comment: This is an first order differential equation whose integration factor is $e^{-e^{x}}$

Comment: @user1337, I got $f'(x) = - \exp(e^x)$. But what function gives such a derivative?

Comment: @Mann, thanks. Still, I need to figure out the integral of $exp(e^x)$

Comment: Yep, Maybe try wolfram alpha it might give a hint, The function i get is I will write in answer.

Comment: @Mann, anyway, thanks for help!

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28e%5E%282x%29-e%5E%28x%29%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=-e^{e^{x}}\left(\int e^{(e^{2x}-e^{x})} dx\right)+c e^{e^{x}}$ is what I get after , simplifying a little, but the integral is a problem

Edit: It has no elementary solution, as shown by wolfram alpha.